# Finding the ptrap to unclog the kitchen sink

Tags: drain, sink, clog, p-trap

I am trying to unclog my kitchen drain and unsure if the black section in the first picture is the p-trap or not? I am trying to avoid opening up something that I should not be trying to open up. I also uploaded a second picture to show something that is below the sink area, in case the  p-trap is there? I do not know how to access below there if so.

Based on what I read, it sounds like this is not the p-trap (needs to be shaped to trap water) but I wanted to be sure, before I called a plumber to help me out.

I tried boiling water and plunging but both have not worked yet.

[image: is this the ptrap?]
[image: could it be down here?]

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a p-trap, unless it's below.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're right, I'll look into plunging some more to see if it helps!

Comment: Stop putting boiing water in the drain. This could damage the plastic drain pipes (ABS polymer?). Where is this--country and state?

Comment: it is Canada, Ontario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a p-trap in your plumbing.

If you wish to have one, you will have to install it.

A DIY with plumbing experience can do that, otherwise call a plumber.

You have enough space to install it.